# How to collect new urls which has been found in new version

Tags: aem, jcr

I would like to get the urls that the author added in new Version of some page.

> Example: author adds www.url1.com in myPage and activate myPage. -->
>   version 1.0 is generated
>            author adds www.url2.com in myPage and activate myPage. --> version 1.2 is generated -> myPage version 1.2 has bouth  www.url1.com
>   and www.url2.com

The function has to return www.url2.com in this case.

I wrote a function **getNewUrls(Set>String> urls)** which collects the urls from the old version and the new version and deletes the old found urls from the new found urls as follow.

```
private Set<String> getNewUrls(Set<String> urls){
   Set<String> newUrls = collectUrlsFromNodes(newVersionNode.getNodes());
   Set<String> oldUrls = collectUrlsFromNodes(oldVersionNode.getNodes());
   Set<String> myNewUrls newUrls.removeAll(oldUrls);
 }

private Set<String> collectUrlsFromNodes(final NodeIterator nodeIter) {

        Set<String> urlSet = new HashSet<String>();
        while (nodeIter.hasNext()) {
            Node subNode = nodeIter.nextNode();
            urlSet.addAll(collectUrlsFromNodes(subNode.getNodes()));
            if (subNode.hasProperty("fileReference")) {
                String url = subNode.getProperty("fileReference").getString();
                urlSet.add(url);
            }
        }
        return urlSet;
    }
```

Prolbem is that this function find also the urls, that the author already deleted too (mybe because they still stored in content even when the author delete/edit urls from the page). Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding you correctly, you are creating a new node on each revision of myPage?  If so, I would check how the new node is being created.  Look in CRXDE and compare the different nodes.  Make sure they are different.

Comment: every new node is created. all node are created on the same way. one node is created, when author added new url in the page.